# What is the reason for failure of simple slicing in my script in R?

Tags: r, slice

I am trying use simple slice operator as follows, but the result is not correct.

```
arr = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
arr[2:2+3]
```

I expected to get the sliced array `2,3,4,5` but instead I get `5`. Does R interpret `arr[2:2+3]` as `arr[2:2]+3` ? If so, then why?

The correct version of slice would be `arr[2:(2+3)]`, right?

Comment: Order of operations. `2:2+3` gives you 5. `2:2` is the sequence of integers from 2 to 2, i.e. only the number 2. Then you're adding 3.

Comment: @camille It makes a lot sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @camille pointed out in the comment section, the reason of failure is due to the order of operations!